# nodemcu two and more leds control

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

Please your help with code for two and more leds control on Nodemcu, i have a code for one led control and cant make it work for two or more. I find this amazing code on Martyn Currey website and write him but not get the answer so i ask yor help . I have a great code what alow me control one led from web on nodemcu , i would like to control two separated leds, please your help . here is the code :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char WiFiPassword[] = "wifi";
const char AP_NameChar[] = "wifi" ;
WiFiServer server(80);
String header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
String html_1 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/><meta charset='utf-8'><style>body {font-size:140%;} #main {display: table; margin: auto;  padding: 0 10px 0 10px; } h2,{text-align:center; } .button { padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; width:100%;  background-color: #4CAF50; font-size: 120%;}</style><title>LED Control</title></head><body><div id='main'><h2>LED Control</h2>";
String html_2 = "";
String html_4 = "</div></body></html>";

String request = "";
int LED_Pin = D7;
int LED_Pin2 = D8;

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(LED_Pin, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(LED_Pin2, OUTPUT); 

    boolean conn = WiFi.softAP(AP_NameChar, WiFiPassword);
    server.begin();

} // void setup()

void loop() 
{

    // Check if a client has connected
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (!client)  {  return;  }

    // Read the first line of the request
    request = client.readStringUntil('\r');

    if       ( request.indexOf("LEDON") > 0 )  { digitalWrite(LED_Pin, HIGH);  }
    else if  ( request.indexOf("LEDOFF") > 0 ) { digitalWrite(LED_Pin, LOW);   }

    // Get the LED pin status and create the LED status message
    if (digitalRead(LED_Pin) == HIGH) 
    {
        // the LED is on so the button needs to say turn it off
       html_2 = "<form id='F1' action='LEDOFF'><input class='button' type='submit' value='Turn of the LED' ></form><br>";
    }
    else                              
    {
        // the LED is off so the button needs to say turn it on
    html_2 = "<form id='F1' action='LEDON'><input class='button' type='submit' value='Turn on the LED' ></form><br>";
    }

    client.flush();

    client.print( header );
    client.print( html_1 );    
    client.print( html_2 );
    client.print( html_4);

    delay(5);
  // The client will actually be disconnected when the function returns and 'client' object is detroyed

} // void loop()
```

please your help.

Comment: friends also any another script for nodemcu to control two and more leds will be real helpful .

Comment: please read [ask]. we are happy to help you solve a distinct programming problem if you present some own attempts. just posting third party code and requesting changes won't yield much support.

Comment: please read question again , i not ask to change existed third party code i post it as example , i ask for some example of code. any way i already get perfect and quick help on Arduino forum .